# Microsoft Surface: Where to define methods that have only be called during startup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I have some methods, that should only be called during startup of the application. For now, I placed the methods in OnApplicationActivated:

```
private void OnApplicationActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Sound.loadSounds();             
   GetLocalProjects();
   GetProjects();            
}
```

But OnApplicationActivated isalso called, if the application was in the "pause" state (the shell is displayed) and is reactived. How can I avoid this? I want to call these methods only during startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Microsoft Surface so I can't tell you if there are some other event that could be hooked up, but wouldn't an easy fix be to use a boolean instance variable to check whether initialization has been done or not?

```
bool _isInitialized = false;
private void OnApplicationActivated(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
  if( !_isInitialized ){
    Sound.loadSounds();
    GetLocalProjects();
    GetProjects();          
    _isInitialized = true;   
  }
}
```

Comment: haha, yepp...maybe you are the positive kind and I'm a negative.. regarding the initial values of the booleans :)

Comment: Ok this is obvious, but thans anyway, if I can't find a builtin function, Ill do this

Comment: Well, you never know what's obvious to different people ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean startup = true;
private void OnApplicationActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   If (startup)
   {
   Sound.loadSounds();             
   GetLocalProjects();
   GetProjects();
   startup = false; 
   }           
}
```

The Best fastest solution i could come up with

Answer (score 0):

How would you do this for a non-Surface application?  Override OnInitialized in your main window.